# Как в конструкторе класса инициализировать поле класса, являющееся объектом и созданное на стеке?

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, конструктор

Как в конструкторе класса инициализировать поле класса, являющееся объектом класса и созданное на стеке? Следующий код вызывает ошибку.

```
  class A{
    public:
        A(int x, int y){
            this->x = x;
            this->y = y;
        };
    private:
        int x;
        int y;
    };
    
    class B{
    public:
        B(int x, int y){
            A(x, y);
        };
    private:
        A obj;
    };
```

Comment: Инициализация в конструкторе происходит в списке инициализации, а `A(x, y);` создает неименованный временный объект.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class B{
public:
    B(int x, int y):obj(x, y)
    {
    };
private:
    A obj;
};
```

Да, кстати, и конструктор `A` лучше переписать как

```
A(int x, int y):x(x),y(y){}
```